# How do I get the system to exit if the user is wrong?

Tags: java, arrays

If the user guesses wrong the system prints out wrong. I want the game to end whenever the user is wrong, can anyone help me? I tried using a system exit but that was exiting when the guess was correct as well. I want the system to print "Game Over" if the user is wrong and for the next cards to appear after that.

```
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] cards = {6,4,2,7,5,9,11,1,12};

        System.out.println("predict next number by typing in 'higher' or 'lower'");

        for (int i = 1; i < cards.length; i++)
        {
            printHead(cards, i);
            System.out.println("");;
            String predict = console.next();
            if (predict.equals("higher"))
                checkHigher(cards, i-1, i);
            if (predict.equals("lower"))
                checkLower(cards, i-1, i);
        }
        printAll(cards);            
    }

    public static void printAll(int[] cards){
        for (int i =0; i< cards.length; i++)
            System.out.print(cards[i]+ " ");
    }

    public static void printHead(int[] cards, int upTo){
        for (int i =0; i< upTo; i++)
            System.out.print(cards[i]+ " ");
    }

    public static void checkHigher (int[] cards, int pos1, int pos2){
        if (cards[pos2]>cards[pos1])
             System.out.println ("Correct!");
        else 
             System.out.println("Wrong");
    }

    public static void checkLower (int[] cards, int pos1, int pos2){
        if (cards[pos2]<cards[pos1])
            System.out.println ("Correct!");
        else 
            System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: "I tried using a system exit but that was exiting when the guess was correct as well." Did you maybe forget to add `{` and `}` around your two statements?

Comment: `I want the system to print "Game Over" if the user is wrong and...` - so you want to System exit or print something?

Answer (score 1):

The simpler way is to exit from the program with a

```
System.exit(0);
```

An alternative is to return a `boolean` value from each check and use it to decide if exit or not.

A third alternative is to wrap the `main` method code in a `try catch` and  through an `Exception` when the user is wrong, then exit.

Follow the three alternatives with snippet of codes:

---

**Exiting directly from the check**

```
public static void checkLower (int[] cards, int pos1, int pos2){
    if (cards[pos2]<cards[pos1]) {
        System.out.println ("Correct!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

---

**Use a boolean return value**

```
public boolean void checkLower (int[] cards, int pos1, int pos2){
    if (cards[pos2]<cards[pos1]) {
        System.out.println ("Correct!");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in the main

```
if (!checkLower(cards, i-1, i)) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

---

**Throw an exception**

```
public boolean void checkLower (int[] cards, int pos1, int pos2) throws Exception {
    if (cards[pos2]<cards[pos1]) {
        System.out.println ("Correct!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
        throw new Exception("Wrong answer");
    }
}
```

and in the main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Your code here
    } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("There was an exception in the input");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply type this after every single wrong answer:

```
System.exit(0);
```

> I tried using a system exit but that was exiting when the guess was
>   correct as well.

That's probably because you used else statement istead of else code block. Forgot about braces?